# Right way to resolve gerrit "pending changes" merge conflict

Tags: git, gerrit, git-rebase

I uploaded a database into gerrit. Lets call this A. It got reviewed and verified. When I try to "submit patch set1", I got  a message like below

> The change could not be merged due to a path conflict.
>
> Please rebase the change locally and upload the rebased commit for review.

So, I did the following:

1. Used download command in the gui to fetch this change set.
2. `git rebase origin/master`
3. `fix merge conflicts`
4. `git add <path>`
5. `git rebase --continue`
6. `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

Now, it uploaded another change set for review(lets call this as B). It is same as A except merge conflicts are resolved.

My question is: What I should do with original A database?

Comment: I am thinking of "abandon Change" for A and "submit patch set1" for B. Is it the right way?

Comment: Database? You should keep the `Change-Id:` line in the commit message, then Gerrit will recognize the second push as the second patch set.

Comment: And yes, as said by my predecessor, the previous change can now be closed using the _Abandon_ button.